# Looping through SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

Please help.

I can't loop the imageUrl. it only returns one Image rather than iteration through all the images

```
"images" : [
      {
        "resturantId" : "919db18e-f5e2-4a6b-1df8-08d747e8c08c",
        "id" : "e722f447-a7b8-467c-9b5a-08d747ea79eb",
        "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/149356549.v2.pressablecdn.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/02\/dominos-pizza.jpg"
      },
      {
        "resturantId" : "919db18e-f5e2-4a6b-1df8-08d747e8c08c",
        "id" : "e6f42a59-f7a1-4a27-9b5b-08d747ea79eb",
        "imageUrl" : "https:\/\/www.pymnts.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/02\/dominos-earnings-q4-growth.jpg"
      },
      {
        "resturantId" : "919db18e-f5e2-4a6b-1df8-08d747e8c08c",
        "id" : "d10e91eb-8d44-477b-9b5c-08d747ea79eb",
        "imageUrl" : "http:\/\/apparelmagazine.co.nz\/restaurantandcafe\/wp-content\/uploads\/sites\/3\/2019\/06\/DOminos.jpg?w=640"
      }
    ]
```

---

```
func updateRestImage(json : JSON) {

    for for (index, subJson) in json {
        if let restuarantName = subJson["images"][0]["imageUrl"].string {
            print("jnfvjfvjfvubfuvbfuvb yessssss\(restuarantName)")

        }

     }

   restuarantTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `index` inside the loop, perhaps `["images"][index]...`

Comment: Paste your JSON in question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `index` is the count for `json` not `images` so it may crash

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i used Index and it didn't work

Answer (score 5):

Change the value of images index

```
func updateRestImage(json : JSON) {
    let yourRequiredImagesArray = returnJson["images"].arrayValue.compactMap {return Image(data: try! $0.rawData())}

    if !yourRequiredImagesArray.isEmpty{
   restuarantTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Your model be like

```
struct Image: Codable {
    let imageUrl
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case imageUrl
    }
}

extension Image {
    init?(data: Data) {
        guard let img = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Image.self, from: data) else { return nil }
        self = img
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `[0]`  index with no change

```
func updateRestImage(json : JSON) { 
     for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
           for item in subJson["images"].array {
                 if let res = item["imageUrl"].string {
                   print("yessssss\(res)")
                 } 
            } 
      } 
    restuarantTableView.reloadData() 
}
```

Comment: whats the use of this iteration `for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json`

Comment: There's an Object before ["images"]