# Decoding Nested Json, Missing objects using SwiftyJson iOS

Tags: ios, swifty-json, codable

Im calling this api to receive single rocket launch event:
https://launchlibrary.net/1.4/launch/next/1 using simple `Get` request.
Trying to decode using `SwiftyJson` (also tried `Codable`) with lack of success to read the "rocket" -> "imageURL"

here is my code:

```
struct LaunchHistory {
var launches = [LaunchItem]()

init(with json:JSON) {
    for launch in json["launches"].arrayValue {
        let launchItem = LaunchItem(with: launch)
        launches.append(launchItem)
     }
   }
 }


struct LaunchItem {
let id:Int?
let name: String?
let tbddate: Int?
let status: LaunchStatus?
let rocketImage: String?

init(with json:JSON) {
    self.id = json["id"].int
    self.name = json["name"].string
    self.tbddate = json["tbddate"].int
    self.status = LaunchStatus(rawValue: json["status"].int ?? 0)
    self.rocketImage = json["rocket"]["imageURL"].string
    }
}
```

when `LaunchItem` decoded, all i 11 properties/key instead of almost double.
the `rocket` object is missing.
what am i missing here?

thanks!

Comment: You can follow this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374519/looping-through-swiftyjson/58374946#58374946]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy with `(De)Codable`

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let launches : [LaunchItem]
}

struct LaunchItem : Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let tbddate: Int
    let rocket: Rocket
}

struct Rocket : Decodable {
    let imageURL : URL
}
```

---

```
let url = URL(string: "https://launchlibrary.net/1.4/launch/next/1")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
        print(result.launches.first?.rocket.imageURL ?? "n/a")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
task.resume()
```

Comment: look pretty much as i did (the codable part which i not added), but it works :) thanks for the help. ill try to look into the diffrences